# Logging application use in python?

Tags: python, flask

I'd like to log every time someone uses my Flask app. I'd ideally have a log that looks something like this

```
Timestamp
923829832
929299292
999993939
```

With a list of Unix time stamps that would represent each time a user had accessed the application. What's a good way to do this?

Comment: Do the simplest thing that could possibly work, and see how it goes.

Comment: Your HTTP server *already produces such logs*; that's what access logging is for. Why do you need additional timestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Flask's [after_request](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.after_request) decorator.

For example:

```
import datetime
import time

@app.after_request
def log():
    with open("app.log", "a") as log:
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        log.write(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))
```

This will open a log file after each request, and log the timestamp to the end of it.